# XCOV code coverage not considering .xcovignore file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, code-coverage, fastlane

Hi I am using XCOV plugIn for Xcode Code Coverage.

Total code coverage publishing correctly. but I need to exclude some files from code coverage.

I have mentioned the code .xcovignore file below.
[image]

My fastfile lane code:

```
lane :CodeCoverage do 
      xcov(
          workspace: "sample.xcworkspace",
          scheme: "sample",
          output_directory: "fastlane/xcov_report",
          ignore_file_path: "./.xcovignore"
          #include_test_targets: true
      )
end
```

I have mentioned the .xcovignore file path in "ignore_file_path"

after running the command in terminal. result published on index.html file.
but mentioned files are not ignored from code coverage.

Let me know any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have cleared the above issue.
issue was in my .xcovignore file.
**Issue**
.xcovignore file saved with an extension of .yml. so that issue occurred.

**Solution**
save .xcovignore file without extension.
Now xcov ignores files mentioned .xcovignore

**For your reference:**

[image]